# Compiling a kernel module with some options

Tags: linux, compiling, kernel-modules, make

I have a bug in a driver (`iwlwifi`/`iwlagn`), which I have reported, and the developers are asking me to "build the driver with debug options enabled."  [More specifically](http://intellinuxwireless.org/?n=fw_error_report):

> Debugging output is enabled when compiling the driver with `CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG` set to "`y`".

I do have the source. How do I put that option in when compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This debugging option i.e. CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG is used for enabling the debugging of your WiFi card.

You have to enable this option by adding a line in the .config file in the  /usr/src/linux-headers-(kernel-version) directory.

`CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG=y`

This .config file contains all the kernel options which you want to use while compiling the kernel.

Comment: What does boot have with compiling a kernel? Also, can't the module be compiled on its own?

Comment: @jonallard You can compile a module on its own, but if it's shipped with the kernel, it's easier to take the `.config` from your distribution, run `make menuconfig` or `make xonfig` to add the debug option you want and recompile everything.

Comment: @Gilles That's helpful, thank you. Why would it be easier to recompile the whole kernel rather than only a module? That seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @jonallard There are preexisting tutorials and commands to compile a whole kernel; the computer may churn for a long time, but it's easier for you than finding the appropriate commands to compile a module for your running kernel.

Comment: @Gilles My question was: why is it so? A module is smaller than the whole kernel, so why is it easier to compile the whole thing rather than a small part of it?

Comment: If (big **if**) the configuration change doesn't affect anything else, it should be enough to just do a "make modules" in the directory of the driver (presumably it requires the rest has been built beforehand).